# Need help with limit proving.

Tags: limits, proof-writing

Is it safe to say that $\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}}\rightarrow1$ if $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})=0$$?

Because I want to prove that $\sqrt{n+1}\sim\sqrt{n}\ $when $n\to\infty$, but I don't know how to approach from $\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}}\rightarrow1$. So I was thinking whether by showing $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})=0$ will work.

Thx guys.

Edited: I forgot to mention I have to use the $\mathcal{E}-N$ argument to prove this limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For, $\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}}=\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}} $

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty} (\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}) = 1 $

**Also**,$\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} = \frac{(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}} $

So,$\lim_{n\to\infty} (\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}) = \lim_{n\to\infty} (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}) = 0 $

Then, dividing bothsides by $\sqrt{n} $ ,
So,$\lim_{n\to\infty} (\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}}-1)=0 \implies \lim_{n\to\infty} (\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}) = 1 $

**Edit**: clearly, $\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}}=\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}} $

Now by Archimedean property, for any $\epsilon>0 $ , there exists $m\in \mathbb{N} $, $\frac{1}{n}< \epsilon $ for all $n \ge m $.

Hence , $\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}-1 < \sqrt{1+\epsilon}-1 < (1+\epsilon)-1= \epsilon $ ,

for all $ n \ge m $

So, $\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}-1 < \epsilon $, for all $ n \ge m $.

Comment: Sorry, but I need to proof using the $\mathcal{E}-N$ argument to prove this. Sorry bout that, just realized I did not mention it in my post.

Comment: Your proof is very easy to understand! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

$$L=\lim_{n\to \infty} [\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}]=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}=0$$

And if $n$ is very large, the dominant term in the numerator of $\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}}$ is $\sqrt{n}$ and that in the denominator is $\sqrt{n}$, hence $$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}}\to \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}}=1.$$